# appendChild() fails when trying to append a value stored in an array

Tags: javascript

The following code deletes all children of a certain element, besides these listed inside the `saved` variable.

```
let rightCol = document.querySelector("#rightCol");
let saved = rightCol.querySelectorAll('._4-u2._3-96._4-u8');
let savedArr = [];

saved.forEach(()=>{
    savedArr.push(saved);
});

rightCol.innerHTML = ''; // Delete all children before retrieving "saved" ones.

for (var i = 0; i < savedArr.length; i++) {
    rightCol.appendChild(savedArr[i]);
};
```

The code fails with this error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.

Why the code fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you presented have 2 errors:

- querySelectorAll should be executed on document.
- you are pushing entire array in for each loop.

here is the working copy

```
let rightCol = document.querySelector("#rightCol");
let saved = document.querySelectorAll('._4-u2._3-96._4-u8');
let savedArr = [];

saved.forEach((s)=> {
    savedArr.push(s);
});

rightCol.innerHTML = ''; // Delete all children before retrieving "saved" ones.

for (var i = 0; i < savedArr.length; i++) {
    rightCol.appendChild(savedArr[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing your collection array for each element in your selection return instead of the elements

Where your code state .each(()=> on the next line, the argument to push should be `this`

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration of `forEach` you are adding the entire `saved` array to `savedArr`. You should instead add each item using the parameter passed into the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback.

e.g.

```
saved.forEach((s)=> {
    savedArr.push(s);
});
```

Not sure why you're copying the array over to another array here though..